# Binary search calculating complexity big o

Tags: algorithms, recursion, big-o-notation

I'm studying recursion and a i have a doubt about the running time complexity of the binary search. I didnt understand this passage in my book :

```
Initially, the number of candidates is n; after the first call in a binary search, it is at
most n/2; after the second call, it is at most n/4; and so on.
```

What if n is a odd number ?

Comment: Cannot read the text you copied

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, $n$ reduces to at most $\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil$, which is $\frac n2$ or $\frac{n+1}2$, depending on the parity of $n$. So you are right. But this can only change the total number of subdivisions by one unit, so it remains essentially $O(\log(n))$.

E.g.
$$27\to13\to6\to3\to1$$ vs. $$27\to14\to7\to4\to2\to1.$$

---

A common technique to handle cases with uneven partitions is to assume that $n$ is a power of $2$, so that all divisions are exact. Then for other $n$, you just notice that the number of partitions is intermediate between those for the bracketing powers of $2$. (E.g. $16<27<32$.)